# The 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework' item selected requires 'Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, .net-framework-version

After upgrading Visual Basic 2008 project to Visual Basic 2010 version, I'm having problem with Setup and Deployment project. When I build the project, it returns the following error:

```
Warning 1   The 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework' item
selected requires 'Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0'. Select the missing prerequisite in the 
Prerequisites Dialog Box or create a bootstrapper package for the missing prerequisite. 
D:\Projects\Point of Sale\POS\Backup1\Setup\Setup.vdproj    Setup

Error   4   To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my 
application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'Crystal Reports 
for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_9.msi' for item 'SAP Crystal Reports 
Runtime Engine for .NET Framework' to your local machine. For more information, see 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.  D:\Projects\Point of Sale\POS\Backup1\Setup\Setup.vdproj    Setup
```

Anyone encounter this problem and have fixed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

google to download 2 files

CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_9.msi
and 
CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_9.msi

copy files to :
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0   for 32 bit

or to

C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0

close visual studio and reopen it, republish your solution

notes : you may asked to download other prerequisites like dot net.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2015, the path is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0
```